# Full memory utilization of a docker container with JVM

Tags: java, docker

We have a Java based micro-service application running in docker container. Since the services require different memory settings, we have to specify the memory limits of both the Docker container and the JVMs (`-Xmx`).

I am aware of that Java has container support from Java 10, but that means only certain options takes the resource limits of the container into consideration.

My question is there any setting that makes the JVM fully utilize the available memory of the container? For example, if the container has 1GB, then the JVM utilizes this by sharing this memory among its heap and non-heap memory(stack, classes etc.) optimally.

Comment: I don't think that there is such a setting. Mainly because Java has only little control over the memory used by the non-heap part. Native libraries , Java internal structures and even the internal data of the GC are not fully predictable.

Comment: @Robert that's true, but at least it has some control over the heap. If more non-heap memory needed, then it could shrink the heap if it's not full. My problem is that by setting these settings manually we can waste a lot of memory if the number of containers are high.

Comment: Shrinking the heap size without manually calling `System.gc()` is a new feature of Java 12. Therefore it can not work on older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic flag that will size the Java memory for you. A workload of one micro-servies might be different from another and will require different memory configuration.

You would have to manually set the `-Xms`, `-Xmx`, and other parameters. If they are not set the JVM will use defaults e.g. `-Xmx` will be defaulted to 25% of available RAM.

Java 8 and 9 have `+XX:+UseContainerSupport` only but [since Java 10](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189497) this is now the default behavior. This option makes the JVM respect the resource limits imposed by the container but doesn't automatically scale the memory.

Comment: yes, the latest is the addition of `+XX:+UseContainerSupport` in Java 10 to behave correctly in containerised environments.